# Firebase support for Xamarin

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

We are developing a mobile application (iOS & Android) in Xamarin. This app will have real-time features like PNS notifications and chat.

Now at this point we were thinking about leveraging **firebase** but there is no official support for **xamarin**. Now we are wondering if we should use firebase libraries that were developed by the Xamarin team.

Alternatively we could develop our own back end server because this is for one of our long-term clients and we will be maintaining the application for a long time.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Xamarin supplies binding (C# wrapper) libraries for the "official" Google/Firebase libraries. Those packages/libraries are not reimplemented versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at the Xamarin developer guide<sup>‡</sup> for implementing FCM seems pretty thorough really.

I've seen plenty of people implement FCM successfully and you can find discussions on their approaches at the xamarin developer forums which can be found [HERE.](https://forums.xamarin.com/)

That being said, we actually favor the use of the Azure notification hub for our cross platform applications. Might be worth taking a look at if you want to consider all of your available options.

[Link 1](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/mobile/Azure/NotificationHubs/) - Sample of how you consume a connection to an azure notification hub.

[Link 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm) - Full google walk through for notification hubs.

[Link 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started) - Full iOS walk through for notification hubs.

[Link 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification) - Full windows walk through for notification hubs

It is worth noting that as the azure notification hub is a Microsoft offering, it is fully compatible with both Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin native projects.

---

<sup>‡</sup>[Xamarin FCM Developer Guide. (Xamarin.Android version)](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/firebase-cloud-messaging/)

[Light weight wrapper for Firebase Realtime Database REST API.](https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin)